# MathJax in the axes labels of Flot

Tags: flot, mathjax

I would like to render LaTeX in the axes labels of Flot.  It works the first pass through on this [page](http://pages.suddenlink.net/physics/discrete/discrete.htm) because this is executed in my header:

```
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$", "$"], ["\\(", "\\)"]]}
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" async src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
```

However, the user has the option of entering new parameters other than the defaults and executing a JS via `<input type="button" value="Evaluate" onclick="discrete()">`.  It's at this point that MathJax fails to "see" what's happening at the end of `discrete.js`:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({//needed?
  tex2jax: {inlineMath: [["$", "$"], ["\\(", "\\)"]]}
});
function doPlot(position) {//Flot
  $.plot("#placeholder", [//data
    { data: z_m_plot }
  ],//options
    {
      series: {
        points: {
          radius: 3,
          show: true,
          fill: true,
          fillColor: "navy"
        },
        color: "navy"
      },
      xaxis: { axisLabel: "$z_{max}(j - 1)$" },
      yaxis: { axisLabel: "$z_{max}(j)$" }
    }
    );
}
doPlot("left");
```

Is there a way to pass individual strings to MathJax in order to render `$z_{max}(j - 1)$` and `$z_{max}(j)$` in the axes labels?

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips (and perhaps update your answer for future readers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MathJax runs on page load and converts the math markup.  If you want it to run again after you redraw your plot [add this](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html):

```
doPlot("left");
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]); // queue up MathJax
```